# How to make a line break for text box

Tags: html, css

[Gap between text boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkv5F.jpg)In first row i had used text boxes with labels. When i use text box with label the text box is attached with first row's text box i had tried to give break line   
 but in mobile view there is showing gap between text boxes from first row to second row text boxes. Instead of break line. This text boxes i am using in accordion.

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #b3daff;">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
               href="#collapseFour"> <span style="font-weight: 700;">Banking
            Details</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"
               style="color: darkred">&nbsp;</span>
            </a>
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">Bank
                     Name</label>
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" required
                           placeholder="Bank Name" />
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">Account
                     Number </label>
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" required
                           placeholder="Account Number" />
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">IFSC
                     CODE </label>
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" required
                           placeholder="IFSC CODE" />
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6">
               <div class="row" style="visibility: hidden">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">IFSC
                     CODE </label>
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" required
                           placeholder="IFSC CODE" />
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <br /><br /><br /><br />
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">Bank
                     Address </label>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">Address
                     Line 1 </label>
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="fname" required
                           placeholder="Address Line 1" ></textarea>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!----Ends second column-------->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a text break use `<br>`

To make a line break (spanning the div) use: `<hr>`

Add classes to the `<br>` and `<hr>` elements to assign custom spacing

Ex: `<br class="small-break">`

CSS:

```
.small-break {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Same problem in mobile view its showing gap. i had posted the image.

Comment: @Learning Try using `margin: auto;` if not then `margin-top: auto;` & `margin-bottom: auto;`. You can also use Relative lengths instead of px (pixels). Read about them here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for breaks just add `<br>` or multiple of them wherever you would like them.

Comment: If i do multiple of <br /> in mobile view showing lot of gap between one text box to another text box.